# ion-searchbar crash the app hitting enter

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

in my angular application I have a searchbar, that works  as expected if I do not press enter, here Mr projectès details:

> Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.5.4
> @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.1101.4    @angular-devkit/schematics
> : 11.2.3    @angular/cli                  : 11.1.4
> @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 3.1.0
>
> Capacitor:
>
> Capacitor CLI   : 2.4.6    @capacitor/core : 2.4.6
>
> Utility:
>
> cordova-res : not installed    native-run  : not installed
>
> System:
>
> NodeJS : v10.19.0 (/usr/bin/node)    npm    : 7.9.0    OS     :
> Linux 5.8

here the code:

html:

```
<form >
   <ion-searchbar [id]="filterString" (ionChange)="onInput($event)"  >
   </ion-searchbar>
</form>
```

.ts

```
onInput(ev) {
    console.log('input',ev.detail.value)
    this.filterFunction = this.makeFilter(ev.detail.value)
    this.filterString = ev.detail.value // spaghetti code waiting to be refactored
}
```

Comment: Hey can you please post the logs of the crash? The console from the it or logs from the device?

Comment: unfortunately, there are no logs on the console, as far, I run app works only on localhost, it crashes  without any log nor on the prompt, nor on chrome's console